# Use of of the word "practitioners"

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been visiting this website a lot but it's the first time I needed to sign up and ask a question. So first of all, thank you for all your help so far!

I'm researching and writing on a participatory music performance practice called "parea" and I often refer to those who participate as "parea participants" or "parea enthusiasts". Yet, at times I need a word that is equivalent to "the people who practice this tradition" and for that I have been using the phrase "parea practitioners". English is not my first language so I'm worried in case "parea practitioners" could sound strange--or even be misinterpreted--in English. According to the Oxford Dictionary it stands for "a person actively engaged in an art, discipline, or profession, especially medicine".
Yet, would you think that my use of the word "practitioner" is strange or even wrong?

Many thanks,

John

Comment: It sounds fine to me (native English speaker), for whatever that may be worth. :-)

Comment: It is not wrong. It puts *parea* in the spotlight. Besides, using *parea practitioners* has a certain ring to it, which maybe because of the alliteration.

Comment: "the people who practice this tradition". Does it mean people who perform or do repeatedly in order to acquire skill or proficiency, or people who train or drill themselves in order to learn it?

Answer (score 1):

> Parea Practitioner

Does sound a little strange, because it implies the person is practicing/engaged in 'parea' which if I understand your question correctly isn't the case, they are practicing music, and performing 'parea' the name of the music piece?

If that is the case I would suggest:

> Parea **Performers**

As a more usual turn of phrase to describe the situation you have outlined.

Here are some examples of 'performers' being used in a similar context:

> 1. [Cirque Musica](http://www.reviewjournal.com/entertainment/arts-culture/cirque-musica-borrows-local-symphony-performers-holiday-show) borrows local symphony performers for holiday show
> 2. [Symphony performers](http://www.thedailyjournal.com/story/life/people/2015/01/29/symphony-performers-play-salon-concert/22356105/) to play at salon concert
> 3. [Original ‘The Last Waltz’](https://www.jambase.com/article/original-last-waltz-performers-take-part-40th-anniversary-celebration) Performers To Take Part In 40th Anniversary Celebration

Comment: *Parea* seems to be an imported Greek word that refers to folk music enthusiasts who gather in small groups and play/sing this form of music. It is not the name of a specific song.

Comment: Many thanks for your answers! 

The "parea performers" is a more specific phrase which I already employ to refer to those playing at a given moment. However, since the parea is a participatory performance (rather than staged) not all of the participants are performers.

@torek The word parea commonly translates as "company" (it derives from the Latin pār that means "equal" or "match"). As you pointed out sometimes it also refers to folk music participatory performances; in the case of my study in Crete, Greece.

Many thanks again,
John

Comment: @JohnPap I think I understand better, what the word is set to convey now. So people who have practiced this form of musical expression throughout time? I would say actually 'parea participants' works fine as is, they do not need to be actively participating to have 'been' a prior 'participant'.

Comment: @Gary Yes, it is "people who have practiced this form of musical expression throughout time". Yet, I think that "p. participants" either refers to those who participate in a given parea, including those who are not attentive to the practice--or may not even like it. That's why I'm looking for another word. "p. enthusiasts" is more accurate since it indicates that the participants like what they're doing, yet it does not render the meaning I'm trying to convey: "the people who _practice_ this tradition". This why I am considering "p. practitioners". Do you think that the latter is problematic?